# Is there a PROC statement for Gaussian Process Regression?

Tags: sas

Python has an implementation of Gaussian Process Regression (found here:http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html).

I am wondering if SAS has something similar.  A google search for gaussian process regression doesn't yield much, so perhaps it is under another name.